# How to detect route change in microfrontend app

Tags: reactjs

I have microfrontend app consisting of two react projects let's call them A and B and if a user clicks a certain link in A project then url is changed. But how can I detect url change in project B. Now I have componentDidUpdate function which checks current location.pathname with previous one. But componentDidUpdate is run only when url is changed within A or B.

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const {
          location,
        } = this.props;
        if (location.pathname.includes('/messages/inbox/') && prevProps.location.pathname !== location.pathname) {
          ...logic code
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reatc-router` OR `react-router-dom`, handle it by `useEffect`

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Changed");
    }, [location.pathname]);

    return ();
}

export default App;
```

You can handle `locaton.search` instead of `location.pathname`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `history.listen` method when trying to detect the route are change.

[Docs:](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener)

You can listen for changes to the current location using `history.listen`.

Example :

```
    useEffect(() => {
      // To start listening for location changes...
      const unlisten = history.listen(({ action, location }) => {
        // The current location changed.
      });

      // Later, when you are done listening for changes
      // should have cleanup to remove them
      return () => {
        unlisten();
      };
  }, [])
```